# How do I map the Meta key to Option on Sierra?

Tags: macos-sierra

There doesn't seem to be a box to check to achieve this under System Preferences->Keyboard on Mac OS Sierra - or I haven't found it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The concept of a <kbd>Meta</kbd> key only exists in certain applications, and they use their own preferences. For instance, in `Terminal`, go to `Preferences -> Profiles`, select a profile, go to the `Keyboard` tab and check **Use Option as Meta key**